# Which design pattern is followed while iterating rowset?

Tags: java, row

Here is the sample code. Since there is not source to backtrack given a code get the pattern.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM Table1");

    while (rs.next()) {
        int x = rs.getInt("a");
        String s = rs.getString("b");
        float f = rs.getFloat("c");
    }
```

I think this is some pattern, has a name and has more applications which I am unaware about. Let me know the pattern name ?

Comment: your question is not clear..what pattern?

Comment: You just access the variables. Do you want to put variable to a wrapper class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ResultSet is an instance of the [Iterator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) pattern. But not the `java.util.Iterator` interface.

[Iterator as ArrayList http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4589598971789992&pid=15.1](http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=H.4589598971789992&pid=15.1)

Comment: `But not the java.util.Iterator interface` thanks for this this much needed clarification, 1 up just for that :)

Answer (score 2):

the patten name is "Iterator Pattern".